# Is there any tool for identifying error in htm page and also for java script

Tags: javascript, html

Pls any one help me to identifying error in javascript and html.

If i am using asp.net c#,  using break point to rectify the errors, but how can i done these process(break point) in javascript and html

Comment: `console.log();` or `console.debug();` and use the google chrome console or firefox's

Comment: you can't break html : this is just a presentation layer. To debug javascript, you may use firebug for firefox or just press F12 in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio for your .NET developing? If so, you can place breakpoints in the javascript code as well.

But I'd suggest that you use the browsers built-in developer tools for this, which usually is accessed by pressing F12. There you can easily play around with both parts of scripts and edit your html.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is you could put alert at some points where you think something could go wrong in the code.

Next option is you could press F12 or press ctrl+shift+i on the keyboard to get the console.This works on chrome..I would suggest you to use this option.I think in firefox there is firebug similar to this..Never used it though

Answer (score 0):

Every browser have a debugger for scripts. But if you can't used to them you cand easy install and use CompanionJs. Below you have the download link:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using firefox browser, you can install the Firebug add on that is extensively used for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox plugin FireBug.Its easy and help you to solve errors and page statistics.

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)